# How to make CarouselView respond to CurrentItemChanged in MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

So I'm trying to work with CarouselView and it's been really complicated. After some researches I see that there are a lot of bugs but I haven't been able to work around this simple scenario:

I want to know about the currently selected value, and know when it changes. So I did the following:

```
 <CarouselView VerticalOptions="Center" PeekAreaInsets="65" Loop="True"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Minutes}" CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedMinute}" CurrentItemChanged="carouselMinutes_CurrentItemChanged">
 <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
```

Out of the box, CurrentItem property does not work at all that it why I registered to the CurrentItemChanged event, but when I scroll it is never raised. Any input is appreciated, thanks a lot.

EDIT: updating to .NET 8 preview solved my issues and I am now able to properly work with the CarouselView control.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. When I scroll the carouselview on the screen, the currentitem property would change and CurrentItemChanged event would fire.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about this scenario or share more code to reproduce this issue?  Also more detail information please,  what platform, .net version, and in debug or release mode. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. It seems that all the issues I faced were solved when I updated from .NET 7 to .NET 8 preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small demo to fire the CurrentItemChanged event, you may have a try.

```
<Label x:Name="mylabel" TextColor="Red" FontSize="50"/>

<CarouselView VerticalOptions="Center" PeekAreaInsets="65" Loop="True"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"
              CurrentItemChanged="CarouselView_CurrentItemChanged">
```

And each time we scroll the CarouselView, we change the text of label:

```
void CarouselView_CurrentItemChanged(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.CurrentItemChangedEventArgs e)
{

    mylabel.Text = viewModel.CurrentItem.Name;
}
```

Here is the effect:

[image]